# SQL Table - How to add a row at the start of an old autoincrement column

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have an existing sql table with 3 columns and 100+ entries/rows. There is an id column with autoincrement.

Now, I want to add 10 new rows at the beginning of the table with id from 1 to 10. But I cannot lose any existing row. So, how do I do it?

One idea that just came to my mind is perhaps I can increase the existing id by adding 10, like 1+10 becomes 11, 25+10 becomes 35, and then I can add rows at the beginning. What will be the script for this IF this is possible?

Comment: Don't mess with the auto increment values. If you need an order use a different column!

Comment: but, i tried, and it worked. UPDATE `table` SET `id` = `id` + 10

Comment: `I want to add 10 new rows at the beginning of the table with id from 1 to 10` - no, you don't actually want that. I know you *think* you do, but you don't. Everything is possible, and I personally won't supply you with code to commit this atrocity. The solution you're after is forgetting about messing with `auto_increment`, creating another column which you'll call `order_id`, you'll index it, and then you will order your rows upon *retrieval* using that very column. Now, you can take my advice or you can have, oh so much fun when `auto_increment` bites you. And it will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do for this is to set the auto_increment for that table to whatever number you need to create space for the new records you want to insert.

For example, if you inserted rows with id's 1-100, you might:

Check the next auto_increment value by running:

```
select auto_increment as val from information_schema.tables where table_schema='myschema' and table_name='mytable';
```

Let's assume that value would be 101 (the value that would be used if you inserted a new row).  You can "advance" the auto_increment value by running:

```
alter table myschema.mytable auto_increment = 111;
```

If you insert a new row like this:

```
insert into mytable (not_the_id_column) values ('test');
```

It will get the "next" id of 111.  But if you specify id values manually, you are ok in this case as long as you use any value less than 111, so you could insert your desired records like this:

```
insert into mytable (id, not_the_id_column) values (101, 'test101');
insert into mytable (id, not_the_id_column) values (102, 'test102');
... -- more inserts as needed
```

Now, you still must take proper precautions when updating PK values, or any value that has dependencies on it (Foreign Key or otherwise), but it is completely legitimate to forcibly advance and/or backfill the id values, as long as the resulting auto_increment value doesn't duplicate one that's already in the table.

Comment: I must be missing something, how does this answer the question?

Comment: @Uueerdo OP wants to insert 10 new rows where the id (autoincrement column) will end up with values that won't interfere with existing data or future values generated by autoincrement.  This answer simply shows the various ways that MySql's auto_increment setting can be used to address this, without prescribing any overly specific implementation details  (e.g. the explicitly set id values *could* be 1-10, but they may not have to be).

Answer (score -2):

I agree with juergen d's comment that you should not do this, but I realize there are situations where this kind of thing must be done.

```
SELECT MAX(id)-MIN(id)+1 INTO @x FROM theTable;
UPDATE theTable SET id = id + @x;
SELECT MIN(id) INTO @x FROM theTable;
UPDATE theTable SET id = 10 + id - @x;
```

If the id is the primary key, value collisions within an update can cause MySQL to reject the update. (Hence the pair of updates to avoid such a possibility.)

Edit: Factoring N.B.'s strong objection into this, it would also probably be good to verify the table's next auto-increment value is not going to collide with the updated records after the update is completed. I don't have an appropriate database on hand to verify whether UPDATE statements affect it; and even if they do affect it, you may end up wanting to reduce it so as to not create an unnecessary gap (gaps should ideally not be a problem, but if they are or you are just mildly OCD, it is worth looking into).

Comment: The only situation when you have to do this is when you started learning programming a week ago and you falsely assumed that `auto_increment` yields sequential numbers. Providing solutions for this atrocity won't make people learn how to do things right, it will just make them lazy, they'll copy paste this solution and when all hell breaks loose - they'll abandon the project / quit or whatever else. Be careful with how you spread your knowledge, a few internet points are not worth the damage caused.

Comment: @N.B. when you inherit a long term project that you did not start, that relies on id's being in sequential order, and find yourself needing to insert data because the numerous systems just can't handle the current state of it, then others refusing help on principle (and effectively suggesting you rewrite years worth of code) really isn't... well... helpful. ...and what circumstances have you seen MySQL not issue auto_increments in order?

Comment: If you inherited a project that uses `auto_increment` in such a wrong way then you fix it - and the fix is trivial, add a column that acts as ordering one. How do I know? So far, in the past 15 years that I'm doing this work - I've seen and fixed hundreds of such projects. There's just no excuse. If you are an expert, if you are paid to do what you do and if you see something like that - it means that your employer will be hit with technological debt and that means they will ultimately lose money. It's your responsibility to fix it.

Comment: Also, I didn't mention anything about `auto_increment` not issuing numbers in **order**. It implements the order - it always issues larger number than the previous. Sequence means it always issues larger numbers sequentially - i.e. incremented by the same number (1, 2, 3 etc.). `auto_increment` increments number in sequence, but the final result does not have to be **sequential**. It's simply always larger than previous. That means you can get a `1` out of it, then `50`, then `51`, `52`, `10501` and those numbers *aren't* sequential.

Comment: There are plenty of reasons not to; to name two off the top of my head: (1) you are not in a position of the team to make that kind of decision, and/or (2) your project is in a heavily regulated industry where the smallest code change requires submission to an external approval process that is potentially expensive and lengthy; a cost which doesn't help your company, and delay which won't fix the problem for your customers.

Comment: Also, not sure if you noticed, but my suggested solution doesn't make them sequential either; and nothing in the question really suggests the OP assumed anything other than incrementing. So, now that we've eliminated that, what is the issue? _Are you thinking of the even worse scenario of using "staggered" auto-increment values across multiple databases to form a "global" identifier?_

Comment: The issue is that you manually modified the value of an `auto_increment` field. InnoDB storage engine uses the primary key for clustering index. Clustering index is a special type of data structure and it's basically the order in which data is written on the disk. Now, what does this mean? If you alter this value, then MySQL starts reorganizing everything on the disk. At the same time, it's still accepting queries. So, it has to worry about reorganizing + inserting new data + handling concurrency and you just killed its information about the `auto_increment` value.

Comment: And why have you done that? To fix someone's OCD and inability to order their data set upon retrieval. `auto_increment` serves one purpose (towards the developer) - it's to hand out unique numbers, not pretty sequential numbers and it's definitely NOT something that should be altered. I'm not questioning your solution, I'm questioning your judgement whether this is something you should hand out to newbies in exchange for a few SO reputation points. It's irresponsible. I hope you get what I mean.

Comment: I don't see anything in the question referring to display ordering, and you are the only one I see talking about sequential values.

Comment: `Now, I want to add 10 new rows at the beginning of the table with id from 1 to 10.` - there exists no such thing as "beginning" of a table. Anyway, I wrote what I wanted and my vote is here for a reason. I suggest we stop with this chatter, you have your beliefs and I have mine - they aren't matching, so let's agree that we disagree. Your solution is fine but dangerous, I explained why, my vote will stay here for that very reason.